# Have only one instance of Android Service

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service

I have a Service() that is created in my view model init

```
val myClass = MyClass()
val serviceIntent = Intent(application, myClass::class.java)
```

I have an instance of the class so I can update values etc.

When I start the service in the init I call

```
context.stopService(serviceIntent)
context.startService(serviceIntent)
```

In my onDestroy of my Service() I call

```
stopForeground(true)
stopSelf()
```

However the code is being executed more than once, when I debug I have two instances of my service class. Is stopService() not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that multiple instances of my viewmodel where being created. Therefore the service was being created multiple times